# sequelize V6 typescript: get data as plain object with findall

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I'm testing sequelize (using typescript) to replace typeorm.
However, I'm fighting to get data from the database, on a proper format. "proper format" means a record by row as a plain object, which represents bascially an instance of the class.(check the picture with the expected result )
Below is a simple code that is self explicit. Team has several players and a player belongs to a team. In the postgres table, there are 2 teams, the first team as 3 players, the second one has 2 players.
The connection's options to postgres are trivial.

```
    "pg": "^8.3.3",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.5",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"


import { DataTypes, Model, Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import { createDbConnection } from "./DbConnections";

interface ITeamAttributes {
    id: number;
    teamName: string;
}

type ITeamCreationAttributes = Partial<ITeamAttributes> & { id: number };

class Team
    extends Model<ITeamAttributes, ITeamCreationAttributes>
    implements ITeamAttributes {
    public id: number;
    public teamName: string;
    public teamPlayers: Array<Player>;

    static defineModel(
        dbConnection: Sequelize
    ): Model<ITeamAttributes, ITeamCreationAttributes> {
        const table = this.init<Team>(
            {
                id: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    allowNull: false,
                    autoIncrementIdentity: true,
                    primaryKey: true,
                },
                teamName: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
                    allowNull: false,
                    defaultValue: "",
                },
            },
            {
                sequelize: dbConnection,
                tableName: "team",
            }
        );

        return table;
    }

    static defineRelations(): void {
        Team.hasMany(Player, {
            sourceKey: "id",
            foreignKey: "teamId",
            as: "teamPlayers",
        });
    }
}

interface IPlayerAttributes {
    id: number;
    playerName: string;
}

type IPlayerCreationAttributes = Partial<IPlayerAttributes> & { id: number };

class Player
    extends Model<IPlayerAttributes, IPlayerCreationAttributes>
    implements IPlayerAttributes {
    public id: number;
    public playerName: string;
    public playerTeam: Team;

    public static defineModel(
        dbConnection: Sequelize
    ): Model<IPlayerAttributes, IPlayerCreationAttributes> {
        const table = this.init<Player>(
            {
                id: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    allowNull: false,
                    autoIncrementIdentity: true,
                    primaryKey: true,
                },
                playerName: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
                    allowNull: false,
                    defaultValue: "",
                },
            },
            {
                sequelize: dbConnection,
                tableName: "player",
            }
        );

        return table;
    }
    public static defineRelations(): void {
        Player.belongsTo<Player, Team>(Team, {
            foreignKey: "teamId",
            targetKey: "id",
            as: "playerTeam",
        });
    }
}

const main = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const dbConnection: Sequelize = createDbConnection();

    if (dbConnection.authenticate()) {
        Player.defineModel(dbConnection);
        Team.defineModel(dbConnection);
        // relations to be defined after all Model definition
        Player.defineRelations();
        Team.defineRelations();

        await dbConnection.sync();

        const teams: Array<Team> = await Team.findAll<Team>({
            include: [{ association: "teamPlayers" }],
        });
        const players: Array<Player> = await Player.findAll<Player>({
            include: [{ association: "playerTeam" }],
        });

        console.log(teams);
        console.log(players);

        console.log(teams.map((team) => team.get()));
        console.log(players.map((player) => player.get()));

        const tt = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(teams, null, 2)) as Team[];
        const pp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(players, null, 2)) as Player[];

        console.log(tt, pp);

        tt.map((t) => t.teamPlayers.map((p) => console.log(p.playerName)));
    } else {
        console.log("not connected to database");
    }
};

main();
```

the issue is that the only whay to get data as a real instance if the table is doing this :

```
    const tt = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(teams, null, 2)) as Team[];
    const pp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(players, null, 2)) as Player[];
```

the others console.log are not returning the records as a plain object.
I'be tried to add the options `{raw:true}` to the `findAll` call but this is even worst. When getting the Team, instead of receiving a record per team with an array of players(so 2 records), the result is flatterned. There is one reacord for each couple Team/Player, so 2*3 = 6 records.

What is the solution ? Because applying the `JSON.STRINGIFY` and the `JSON.PARSE` is a crappy way to go.

Regards

[Edit]
**here the result of `findAll<Team>()`, this is not an array of Team**
[image]

**here is the result of `findAll<Team>({raw:true})`. There is one record per Team/player. Expected result is one record per team with an array of Player**

[image]

**here is the expected result of `findAll<Team>()` and `findAll<Player>()`. There is one record per Team with the array of Player, and each Player has his team information. This result is getting by applying `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(teams, null, 2)) as Team[]` and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(players, null, 2)) as Player[]`**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `plain` option like this:

```
console.log(teams.map((team) => team.get({ plain: true })));
        console.log(players.map((player) => player.get({ plain: true })));
```

Comment: result is simlar than using JSON stringify & parse. But slowler as I've got to run a map. I'm very confused why the result of ` Model.findAll<T>` is not an array of of T. Typescript inferred the type as `T[]`, but in reality it's not.

Comment: Have added 2 pictures that show how `findAll<Team>()` and `findAll<Team>({raw=true})` are not sending back an instance of the class.

Comment: By default `findAll` returns model instances and not a plain objects. That way you can call various instance methods to destroy, reload or update a certain model instance. If you wish plain objects you should use `get({ plain: true})`

Comment: thanks,  Have accepted your comment and your answer .